# Is there any way to use 'left_index' and 'left_on' at once in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm using pandas to merge two datas.

```
import pandas as pd

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Nimitz','McArthur','George','Eisenhower'],
                    'math':[50,100,60,70],
                    'birth':['01','01','02','03']})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'title':['Nimitz','George','McArthur'],
                    'math':[50,100,60],
                    'tardiness':[0,1,2]})

df3_sp = df3.set_index('name')

pd.merge(df3_sp, df4, left_index=True, right_on='title')
```

I wanted to merge not only column 'name' but also 'math'.
So I tried to use left_index and left_on at once.

```
pd.merge(df3_sp, df4, left_index=True, left_on='math', right_on=['math','name'])
```

But it didn't work as 'left_on' and 'left_index' can not be used at once.
I solved this problem this way.

```
df3_sp2 = df3.set_index(['name','math'])
pd.merge(df3_sp2, df4, left_index=True, right_on=['name','math'])
```

It worked but I wanted to know if there's any other way to deal with this problem
not by using set_index() function but using merge() function.

Comment: should "title" be "name"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can as your `df3_sp` index is named and there is no column with the same name:

```
pd.merge(df3_sp, df4, left_on=['math', 'name'], right_on=['math', 'title'])
```

Output:

```
   math birth   title  tardiness
0    50    01  Nimitz          0
```

Note however, that a merge will lose the index (which might not be an issue as you still have the "title" column).

To avoid this issue, you can [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) before the merge:

```
pd.merge(df3_sp.reset_index(), df4,
         left_on=['math', 'name'], right_on=['math', 'title'])
```

Output:

```
     name  math birth   title  tardiness
0  Nimitz    50    01  Nimitz          0
```

If the column names are identical in both DataFrames, then all columns are kept:

```
pd.merge(df3_sp, df4.rename(columns={'title': 'name'}), on=['math', 'name'])
```

Output:

```
   math    name birth  tardiness
0    50  Nimitz    01          0
```